# Identify which chunk has failed in chunk based step in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am developing a Spring Batch App -

How to understand or write code for ?

1. Identify which chunk has failed in chunk based step?
2. How to identify if reader query taking how much time?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Identify which chunk has failed in chunk based step?

A `ChunkListener` allows you to achieve that. The method `afterChunkError` will be called when an error occurs in a given chunk

> 2. How to identify if reader query taking how much time?

It depends on the reader. `ItemReadListener` is called around each read operation, which is not where the query is typically called. For example, the `JdbcCursorItemReader` executes the query in `openCursor` method. This method is protected, you can override it and time it as needed. For the `JdbcPagingItemReader`, the query for each page is called in the `doReadPage` method, which is also protected, so you can override it and time it as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way if we can get the chunk number or which item is garbage data?

Comment: For chunk number, no, you need to keep a counter in your chunk listener. For invalid items, yes, you could use a `SkipListener` for skipped items during read/process/write phases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think we should give facility to access the chunk no. this really help to find exact chunk and then lowering down chunk size could get the value too

Comment: That's another feature, you can open an issue if you want. For this question, I believe I answered it. So please accept/upvote the answer or let me know if you need other details.